# Sending signal SIGINT to process while executing system call or script by killall -SIGINT

Tags: linux, debian, c, signals, c++

I want to send SIGINT to all processes by name so I am using killall -SIGINT which was working fine. Now I introduced system() call in my c code to run a shell script or shell command which take around 10  seconds to complete. I see that in this case signal handler is not called when I send signal.

When I remove or run it in background that system call it again start working.

Please anyone can suggest me to manage it.

Comment: Without seeing the actual code it is hard to come with suggestions.

Comment: Sample code as follow

Answer (score 3):

from the man page of system(3) -

```
system()  executes a command specified in command by calling /bin/sh -c command, and returns after the command has been completed.  During execution of the
       command, SIGCHLD will be blocked, and SIGINT and SIGQUIT will be ignored.
```

Even though the signal is sent to all processes (specified by name), the parent here ignores SIGINT during the system() call. However, it should respond once the call is completed (during sleep() in your case) - have you tried increasing the sleep window ?

Comment: Thanks I have tested with signal SIGUSR1 its working fine and process is not ignoring while executing system call.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include <signal.h>
 void signalHandler(int);
int main()
{
    struct sigaction sa;
    sa.sa_flags = 0;
    // Setup the signal handler
    sa.sa_handler = signalHandler;
    // Block every signal during the handler
    sigfillset(&sa.sa_mask);  
    if (sigaction(SIGINT, &sa, NULL) == -1) {
    printf("Error: cannot handle SIGINT\n"); 
}

    while(1)
    {
        printf("Start to ping google.com");
        system("ping www.google.com -c 1");
        printf("Stop to ping google.com\n");
        sleep(1);
    }

}

void signalHandler(int signal)
{
    printf("signalHandler: signal = %d\n", signal); 
}
```

Comment: As you see I just try to ping www.google.com for once it is not printing  CsignalHandler: signal = 2 as in signalHandler function. If I comment line of system() function it start receiving signal by killall -SIGINT sigint

Comment: I cannot put my code  on comment so put it as answer as its size too long to fit in comment

Comment: You should [edit](http://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/332967/edit) your question to include the code, this isn't an answer and shouldn't go in a comment even if you could put it in one.